# Java wildcard generic problem: Compiler assumes different types for same object

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, wildcard

I have a problem related to JAVA wildcards and generics. I do not want to post my own complex code, so I will use the `Collection` interface for demonstration:

```
Collection<String> stringCollection = new HashSet<String>();
stringCollection.add("1");
stringCollection.add("2");
stringCollection.add(stringCollection.iterator().next());
```

Here, the last line is no problem. `add()` requires a string and `next()` returns a string.

But:

```
Collection<?> anyCollection = stringCollection;
anyCollection.add(anyCollection.iterator().next());
```

Using the wildcard, Eclipse tells me the error

> The method add(capture#19-of ?) in the type Collection is not applicable for the arguments (capture#20-of ?)

But why? I need to use the wildcarded Collection. Somehow Eclipse just doesn't get that `next()` definitely MUST return an object exactly of the type `add()` requires.

Is there any way to fix this without getting an error? For sure, a cast to `(capture#20-of ?)` doesn't work.

Comment: These aren't Eclipse errors - they are Java compiler errors. You are trying to do something that is specifically not allowed by the Java language definition.

Comment: I'm wondering why this shouldn't be allowed - to me, it seems like a reasonable usage.

Comment: @javanerd: You're just trying to use wildcards for something they aren't intended for. It's easy to do what you want with generics, as I show in my answer... just not wildcards.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add anything but `null` to a `Collection<?>`. Yes, you know that any element that's already in the collection should be able to be added to it, but the type doesn't reflect that. `<?>` and `<? extends Foo>` should only be used when you only need to retrieve objects from the collection and not add to it. Can you show why you need to use a wildcard as opposed to, say, `Collection<E>`?

(I assume you know this, but in your example your collection is a `Set` and as such, adding any element that's already in it will do nothing.)

**Edit:**

From your comment, it sounds to me like you don't want a wildcard but just a generic method:

```
public <T extends PersistenceObject> void doSomething(Dao<T> dao) {
  T o = dao.createNew();
  // ...
  dao.save(o);
}
```

The same would be true of a method that wants to re-add the first element of a `Collection` to it:

```
public <E> boolean reAddFirst(Collection<E> collection) {
  return collection.add(collection.iterator().next());
}
```

The specific type parameter (rather than a wildcard) tells the compiler that the type retrieved from the object is the same type that the object expects to be passed to its method.

Comment: I'm dealing with Data access objects. A DAO has the type parameter which objects it handles (for example, Person or Account - so it would be `Dao<Person>` or `Dao<Account>`). One of my methods gets an unknown-type DAO `Dao<?>` and has to use this DAO for the creation of a new object, populating this object and afterwards saving it using the DAO. So actually my method looks like this:  
`doSomething(Dao<?> dao) {`  
`PersistenceObject o = dao.createNew();`  
`/* determine which kind of persistence object it is and populate it*/`  
`dao.save(o);`  
`}`

(really sorry for the formatting, I'm new)

Comment: I's not a method as such, actually, it's just a piece of code that gets a collection of DAOs - `Collection<Dao<? extends PersistenceObject>>` - and has to do the above describd with each of the collection's DAOs.
But "outsourcing" into a generic method is a good point!

Comment: @javanerd: Yeah, you can just pass each `Dao<? extends PersistenceObject>` to a generic method with a parameter of type `Dao<T extends PersistenceObject>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a string object in to a collection of type `Collection<?>`, because  the type Collection itself means that you dont know the type of the collection, hence the compiler won't allow you to add arbitrary types in it.

One way to fix this is to cast it like so:

```
    Collection<?> c = new HashSet<String>();
    Collection strCol = (Collection<String>)c;
    strCol.add("Suraj");
```

Comment: I do not explicitly want to add a string to the `anyCollection`. I want to add whatever `anyCollection.iterator().next()` gives me, and that is always of the right type. But Eclipse just doesn't get that.

Comment: i dont think its possible trivially

Answer (score 0):

Make anyCollection collection of Object

```
Collection<Object> anyCollection = stringCollection;
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks, but that leads to another Eclipse error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<String> to Collection<Object>